# How to print comma seperated values using array inside div with ngrepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to print comma seperated values with successive loops but getting double comma.

**Update:**

Suppose i have data like this in my array:

```
 var carModel = [model:"1",model:"2"]; 
var carNames = [Name:"Abc",Name:"Xyz"]; 
var Price = 1000;
```

**Expected output:**

```
  1 as Car1,2 as Car2,Abc as Name1,Xyz as Name2,1000 as price
```

**Code:**

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in carModel">
     {{data.model}}
     <div>as</div>
     Car{{ $index + 1 }} 
     <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
 </div>

<div ng-repeat="data in carNames">
     {{data.Name}}
     <div>as</div>
     Car{{ $index + 1 }} 
     <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
 </div>

 <span ng-if="carModel.length > 0 || carNames.length > 0" > , </span>
 <div>
  {{ Price }}
  <div>as</div> price
</div>
```

Now this gives me below output which contains double comma:

```
1 as Car1,2 as Car2,Abc as Name1,,Xyz as Name2,1000 as price
```

Comment: @ryanyuyu Stated in the top:1 as Car1,

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-repeat="data in cars">
     {{data.model}}
     <div>as</div>
     Car{{ $index + 1 }} 
     <span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
 </div>
```

[$last](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) can be used to know if the current element is the last of your collection.

Comment: Ok this worked correctly but i am getting problem when i have 2 successive loops.See my updated question

Comment: Guess you have to work a little bit on your logic here to find the suitable conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Other possible non-Angular solutions:

- If this is merely a long string, and you're not doing anything else with the car data, just assemble the string in javascript with `String.join()`.
- Employ a css-based solution.  For example, using the [`:last-of-type` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).  For example:

  ```
  <div ng-repeat="data in cars" class="car">{{data.model}}
                             <div>as</div>
                             Car{{ $index + 1 }}
  </div>
  ```

  Css:

  ```
  .car::after {
    content: ',';
  }
  .car:last-of-type::after {
    content: '';
  }
  ```

  [Demo on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TpoR8btU2EnzypMek9ho?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and this worked but only problem is that this car:last-of-type::after property is not working with span tag.only working with div